# Realloc produces undefined behavior in C when used with a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, realloc

```
field *field_pointer;

/* Enumerates the whole field by saving the coordinates of the free pieces and the dimensions */
void enum_field(char *filename) {
    FILE *maze;
    maze = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i = 0, j = 0, chr;
    field_pointer = (field *)malloc(sizeof(field *));

    field_pointer->empty_coords = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));
    field_pointer->free_spaces = 0;

    while ((chr = fgetc(maze)) != EOF) {
        if (chr == '\n') {
            i = 0;
            j++;
        } else {
            if (chr != '#') {
                field_pointer->empty_coords[field_pointer->free_spaces] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
                field_pointer->empty_coords[field_pointer->free_spaces][0] = i;
                field_pointer->empty_coords[field_pointer->free_spaces][1] = j;
                field_pointer->free_spaces++;
                // I believe the error is here V
                field_pointer->empty_coords = (int **)realloc(field_pointer->empty_coords,
                                                              (field_pointer->free_spaces + 1) * sizeof(int *));

                if (chr == 'E') {
                    field_pointer->E[0] = i;
                    field_pointer->E[1] = j;
                } else if (chr == 'S') {
                    field_pointer->S[0] = i;
                    field_pointer->S[1] = j;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    field_pointer->x = i;
    field_pointer->y = j;

    fclose(maze);
}
```

Well, so I have this C function here, which helps me enumerate a 2D ASCII maze so I can then turn it into a graph.
The ASCII maze is denoted by `#` as walls, free spaces as walkable road and `S` as Start and `E` as Exit.
The function doesn't work and throws a `0xC0000374` which probably means corrupted heap.
I tried to investigate further and noticed that most likely,
the `realloc` function which is supposed to enlarge the two-dimensional array is at fault.
I am relatively new to C, and have been staring a lot at my code, can you help me with another POV and fresh eyes as to what I might be doing wrong? Here is the layout of the field struct as well:

```
typedef struct field {
    int x, y, free_spaces;
    int **empty_coords;
    int S[2];
    int E[2];
} field;
```

Comment: `field_pointer = (field *) malloc(sizeof(field *));` What is the intention here? `sizeof( filed * )` will return the size of the pointer, 8 bytes in 64 bit systems. Are you trying to allocate memory to hold your `struct field`?

Comment: Exactly, field_pointer is in fact, a pointer to the struct field. I realize now that I should've mentioned that as well. Thanks for "pointing" that out ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a sizing problem in your initial allocation:

`field_pointer = (field *)malloc(sizeof(field *))` should allocate the size of a structure, not that of a pointer. Use `field_pointer = malloc(sizeof(field))` or better:

```
    field_pointer = malloc(sizeof(*field_pointer));
```

Note that you could simplify the code by using a real 2D array instead of a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of 2 `int`.

Also note that there is no need to manipulate the global object until it is fully loaded. Using local variables is recommended. Returning the structure pointer allows for the caller to detect failure to load the maze. It should be the caller responsibility to store the pointer to the global variable is needed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct field {
    int x, y, free_spaces;
    int (*empty_coords)[2];
    int S[2];
    int E[2];
} field;

field *field_pointer;

/* Enumerates the whole field by saving the coordinates of the free pieces and the dimensions */
field *enum_field(const char *filename) {
    FILE *maze = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (maze == NULL)
        return NULL;
    field *fp = calloc(sizeof(*fp), 1);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fclose(maze);
        return NULL;
    }
    fp->free_spaces = 0;
    fp->empty_coords = NULL;
    int i = 0, j = 0, chr;

    while ((chr = fgetc(maze)) != EOF) {
        if (chr == '\n') {
            if (fp->x < i)
                fp->x = i;
            i = 0;
            j++;
        } else {
            if (chr != '#') {
                // allocate space for one extra set of coordinates
                int (*new_coords)[2] = realloc(fp->empty_coords,
                                               (fp->free_spaces + 1) * sizeof(*fp->empty_coords));
                if (!new_coords) {
                    free(fp->empty_coords);
                    free(fp);
                    fclose(maze);
                    return NULL;
                }
                fp = new_coords;
                fp->empty_coords[fp->free_spaces][0] = i;
                fp->empty_coords[fp->free_spaces][1] = j;
                fp->free_spaces++;

                if (chr == 'E') {
                    fp->E[0] = i;
                    fp->E[1] = j;
                } else
                if (chr == 'S') {
                    fp->S[0] = i;
                    fp->S[1] = j;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    fp->y = j;
    fclose(maze);
    // return structure pointer for the caller to store to into field_pointer
    return fp;
}
```

Comment: One last thing I don't understand, what exactly does `int (*new_coords)[2] = realloc(fp->empty_coords,
                                               (fp->free_spaces + 1) * sizeof(*fp->empty_coords));
` 
do, I don't quite understand that line

Comment: @dune: `int (*new_coords)[2]` is a definition for a pointer to an array of arrays of 2 `int`. `realloc` attempts to reallocate the current array with space for an extra element. If it fails, `NULL` is returned and the function frees memory allocated so far, closes the stream and returns `NULL`, otherwise the new pointer is stored to `fp->empty_coords`. The unusual syntax `int (*new_coords)[2]` is the trick to handle dynamically allocated 2D arrays.